# Backbone js dynamic events with variables

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Lets say I got this view:

```
var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#application',
    initialize: function() {
        this.template = template; // Comes from requireJS (not relevant)
        this.$elements = {};
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template);

        this.$elements = {
            signIn: {
                email: $('#sign-in-email'),
                password: $('#sign-in-password')
            }
        };

        // Demonstration.
        this.$elements.signIn.email.myPluginInit();
        this.$elements.signIn.password.myPluginInit();

        //
        // NOTE: How to handle the events?
        //
    }
});
```

I have the this.$elements object, which will contain all the objects of my DOM there, how can I put events on them because with this solution they are variable. This is what I used to do (see backbone.org).

```
var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    'click #sign-in-email': 'clickedSignInEmail',
    'focus #sign-in-password': 'focusSignInPassword'
  }
});
```

Comment: Sounds like you should have a different view structure, you'd use different sub-views depending on what widgets you need on the page. Then your sign-in events would be bound to a sub-view and you wouldn't have variable events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the normal jQuery event handling syntax?

```
this.$elements.signIn.email.click(this.clickedSignInEmail);
this.$elements.signIn.password.focus(this.focusSignInPassword);
```

You can also use the [Backbone.View.delegateEvents](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents) method, but that requires you to construct the events hash from your selectors.

Comment: It works, but that will become a lot of code since this.clickedSignInEmail isn't working, that will replace the "this" value in the "clickedSignInEmail" function, so I have to do "this.$elements.signInEmail.click(function() { self.clickedSignIn; })"

Comment: You can force bind the context by doing this in your `initialize`: `_.bindAll(this);`

Answer (score 8):

> Using [delegateEvents](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents) provides a number of advantages over manually
>   using jQuery to bind events to child elements during render. All
>   attached callbacks are bound to the view before being handed off to
>   jQuery, so when the callbacks are invoked, this continues to refer to
>   the view object. When delegateEvents is run again, perhaps with a
>   different events hash, all callbacks are removed and delegated afresh
>   — useful for views which need to behave differently when in different
>   modes.

Example code:

```
initialiaze: function () {
  // …
  this.events = this.events || {};
  // dynamically build event key
  var eventKey = 'click ' + '#sign-in-email';
  this.events[eventKey] = 'clickedSignInEmail';
  this.delegateEvents();
  // …
}
```

Comment: Better to clone events before applying changes to them inside initialize(): `this.events = _.clone(this.events) | {}`. Otherwise, you'll change global events object, if you defined it. Which is not cool, and will lead to wrong additional event triggering sometimes.

Comment: But `this.events` is going to be specific to the instance of view and then it's exactly what you want to do – you don't want each object to have its own `events` property, you want to change the prototype.

Comment: Ok. In my own particular case, I actually needed own `events` for each view instance. But isn't it strange to change prototype from inside of `initialize`?

Comment: Well perhaps it a good idea to mention it in a comment. Maybe also to make it more obvious a good idea would be to do `this.constructor.prototype.events`.